# Android.view.View setAccessibilityLabel() method. Is there another way?

Tags: java, android, mobile, accessibility

Previously in React Native/JavaScript I used setAccessibilityLabel() method on a View to set the accessibility label.

After moving to native Java, it appears an equivalent method doesn't exist for  Android.view.View.

How is the accessibility label handled for Java class Android.view.View ?

Comment: I'm working on C++ native modules for Android and not really familiar with Java class interfaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `setContentDescription` in native.